# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker main command

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can we specify the command that Elastic Beanstalk must use when running a Docker image?

We can specify a CMD in the Dockerfile, but let's imagine that the image is not ours and we don't want to change the Dockerfile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if elastic beanstalk makes things different but normally you could specify the `--entrypoint` option when using `docker run`

Comment: I'm afraid Elastic Beanstalk doesn't allow one to use flags when running the container.